# Knockout foreach binding not rendering anything

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have, what I thought was a fairly straightforward knockout situation. I have a model that comes in from WebApi that has an array of things with a `Success` element. I need the value of success to determine what of the properties render. I've validated that all the data is coming down from WebApi ok but nothing but the table shell renders. There are no errors in the dev console.

#### The HTML

```
<div id="model1Wrapper">
<table class = "table">
    <thead >
        <tr >
            <th >Stuff</th><th>Things</th> 
        </tr> 
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind = "foreach: $data.historyArray" >
        <!--ko if: Success -->
        <tr class = "success" >
            <td data-bind = "text: $data.ThingA" > </td>
            <td data-bind = "text: ThingB" > </td> 
        </tr>
        <!-- /ko -->

        <!--ko ifnot: Success -->
        <tr class = "danger" >
            <td colspan="3" data-bind = "text: ThingC" > </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </tbody> 
</table>
</div>
```

#### Example Model Data

```
[{
    "ThingA": "A",
    "ThingB": "B",
    "ThingC": "C",
    "Success": false
}, {
    "ThingA": "A",
    "ThingB": "B",
    "ThingC": "C",
    "Success": true
}]
```

This is monitoring a process that has feeds from several endpoints so I have multiple ViewModels on the page. So I framed up a rough example of how that is working elsewhere on the page.

#### That business

```
<script>
    var sampleModelData = [{
        "ThingA": "A",
        "ThingB": "B",
        "ThingC": "C",
        "Success": false
    }, {
        "ThingA": "A",
        "ThingB": "B",
        "ThingC": "C",
        "Success": true
    }]


    var viewModel1 = {
        historyArray: ko.observableArray()
    };

    function onNewHistory(data) {
        viewModel1.historyArray(data);
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel1, document.getElementById("model1Wrapper"));
        onNewHistory(sampleModelData);
    })

</script>
```

I had to mask of some of the speciffics but the gist is, the ajax call returns an array in the example. There is a function that is called to update the new data into the observable and I would expect the table to rerender, it does not.

#### Other deets

- Sometimes there is no model data in the table so I load it and wait
  for an update. All the other Viewmodels are loaded like this but this
  is the only one with an array and the only one I'm having trouble
  with.
- I have tried taking out the if/ifnot business and that does not work.
- Fiddler hates me and I have not been able to set up a clean version of this to try.
- I leafed though some of the related questions and nothing seems to fit my issue. Or the example is much more complicated to apply.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked your console for errors? You have a syntax error in the code above. After fixing the syntax error, [it seems to work fine.](https://jsfiddle.net/pcw47eoj/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in this code:

```
var viewModel1 = {
    historyArray = ko.observableArray();
}
```

You're mixing the syntax for declaring objects with the syntax for code inside functions. When declaring an object, don't use `=` and `;`. Instead use `:` and `,`.

If you change the declaration to something like below, it should work.

```
var viewModel1 = {
    historyArray: ko.observableArray()
}
```

Comment: Hi, sorry when I made the mockup I didn't copy it over correctly. I looked at the version I'm trying to run it is set up the way you stated. I put an edit on the post.

Comment: With that error fixed, the code seems to be working. Here's a fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/5kkt7tkf/2/

Comment: Which points to something wrong on my end. I suppose it's good to know that I understood it well enough to begin with. Time to octogentuple check that code...

Comment: You can also use "classes" instead of the inline object initializer syntax. Lets you reuse and instantiate multiple viewmodels if needed. https://jsfiddle.net/5kkt7tkf/5/

Comment: @JustinGrant I was applying the bindings for another viewmodel on that div from some HTML error I had above it. When it came time to apply these bindings it was already bound and blew up. I upgraded to ko v3 which gave an error message finally and I got it. Thanks for at least confirming what I was doing was directionally correct!

Answer (score 0):

Just adding another answer to this question in case someone comes across it in future. I had this issue and it was a result of initialising my observable array within the method. I didn't mean to do this (copy paste error) and it didn't produce any errors in the console so was difficult to trace.

For example:

```
LoadJSArrayIntoObservable(results) {
    vm.validationResults = ko.observableArray();  <---- THIS IS INVALID. 
    vm.validationResults([]);  <---- THIS IS WHAT I MEANT TO DO!!

    $.each(results, function () {
        try {
            vm.validationResults.push(new ValidationResult(this));
        }
        catch (err) {
            alert(err.message);
        }
    });
```